# Is it possible to grab the 4 numbers from this image using IronOCR?

Tags: ocr, captcha

So me and my friends play a game and they recently changed there images from white background and black letters to black background and colorful letters. and the old ocr that we was created years ago by someone is pretty useless now as the accuracy is very low if not 0% (it just took the old ocr ~250 attempts). So my question would i be able to to extract the text from the following picture [image]

I have never used IronOCR and i tried using the default code to get text from image but the results were weird.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to segment the image first by color (a histogram analysis will tell you colors on the image). Then you can convert the images to b/w and run OCR. You'll get better accuracy.